# Using PYSNMP MIB browser how to determine a scalar or a Tabular oid?

Tags: python-2.7, snmp, pysnmp

I was looking at [this MIB browser code](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/examples/smi/manager/browsing-mib-tree.html#snmp-mib-browser). But the o/p of this do not help me to figure out if an OID is scalar or Tabular in nature,

What I want is something like this :
 ABP-SYSTEM::systemName == 1.3.6.1.4.1.211.1.24.12.100.1.2.**0** ### End '0 'To identify this oid represent a scalar value.####

Preset o/p is something like this:

ABP-SYSTEM::systemName == 1.3.6.1.4.1.211.1.24.12.100.1.2

Is this possible using PYSNMP ?

If I load the MIB file using some other MIB browser it identify the scalar and tabular values.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

With SNMP, OIDs of scalar MIB objects *instances* always end with *.0*. But tabular MIB objects *instances* can also end with *'.0'* (RFC 2578, 7.7 (2)). Note the word *instances* here. MIB objects never (?) end with *.0* I guess.

MIB objects live in MIB files as opposed to MIB objects *instances* which are implemented and reported by live SNMP agents. OID-wise, there is a parent-child relationship between MIB object (parent) and MIB object instances (child for scalars, children for table columns).

Let me offer you this simple script. It walks OID tree loaded from MIB files (thus it only deals with MIB objects). By testing the `mibNode` class you can tell if the object is columnar (`MibTableColumn`) or a scalar (`MibScalar`) or anything else SNMP SMI can possibly provide.

```
from pysnmp.smi import builder, view, compiler, error

mibBuilder = builder.MibBuilder()

# Optionally attach PySMI MIB compiler to deal with ASN.1 MIBs
#compiler.addMibCompiler(mibBuilder, sources=['/usr/share/snmp/mibs'])

mibBuilder.loadModules('SNMPv2-MIB', 'SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB', 'SNMP-COMMUNITY-MIB')

mibView = view.MibViewController(mibBuilder)

oid, label, suffix = mibView.getFirstNodeName()
while True:
    try:
        modName, nodeDesc, suffix = mibView.getNodeLocation(oid)
        mibNode, = mibBuilder.importSymbols(modName, nodeDesc)

        print('%s::%s (%s) -> %s' % (modName, nodeDesc, '.'.join([str(x) for x in oid]), type(mibNode).__name__))

        oid, label, suffix = mibView.getNextNodeName(oid)
    except error.NoSuchObjectError:
        break
```

Here a snippet of its output just to give you an idea:

```
...
SNMPv2-MIB::system (1.3.6.1.2.1.1) -> MibIdentifier
SNMPv2-MIB::sysDescr (1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1) -> MibScalar
SNMPv2-MIB::sysObjectID (1.3.6.1.2.1.1.2) -> MibScalar
SNMPv2-MIB::sysUpTime (1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3) -> MibScalar
...
SNMP-TARGET-MIB::snmpTargetParamsTable (1.3.6.1.6.3.12.1.3) -> MibTable
SNMP-TARGET-MIB::snmpTargetParamsEntry (1.3.6.1.6.3.12.1.3.1) -> MibTableRow
SNMP-TARGET-MIB::snmpTargetParamsName (1.3.6.1.6.3.12.1.3.1.1) -> MibTableColumn
SNMP-TARGET-MIB::snmpTargetParamsMPModel (1.3.6.1.6.3.12.1.3.1.2) -> MibTableColumn
SNMP-TARGET-MIB::snmpTargetParamsSecurityModel (1.3.6.1.6.3.12.1.3.1.3) -> MibTableColumn
...
```

If you want to branch based on MIB node type, you could use `isinstance()` against MIB objects like `MibScalar`, `MibTableColumn` etc. To get hold of these classes you could import them from the core MIB like this:

```
MibScalar, MibTableColumn = mibBuilder.importSymbols('SNMPv2-SMI', 'MibScalar', 'MibTableColumn')
```

Comment: A non-zero single index indicates a tabular object, but the converse is not true. While that is true for INTEGER indices, for other types the value .0 is legal in tabular objects. See RFC 2578, 7.7 (2) and following. Eg. a fixed-length 1-character OCTET STRING. Admittedly rare.

Comment: @Ilya but when I am browsing the MIB using PYSNMP, scalar oids like systemName do not ends with .0. is there any way to do that ?

Comment: @user3502325 If you are browsing MIB definitions rather than SNMP agent implementing that MIB, you are getting MIB objects which may end with anything. When you are browsing SNMP agent, what you get is MIB objects *instances* -- OIDs of those include the (trailing) index part which has that '.0' situation we just discussed.

Comment: @GambitSupport Oh, right, that's my bad. I am going to fix my answer.

Comment: @Ilya the above code works fine, just what I wanted. But with pysnmp 4.3.2 this type(mibNode).__name__ does not print out scalar. it just say instance.  >>> type(mibNode)
<type 'instance'>
>>> type(mibNode).__name__
'instance'
>>>
any way I got what I need the way how to identify different object type. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user3502325 That is related to your Python version, not pysnmp. Either try `mibNode.__class__.__name__` or use `isinsntance` as I just mentioned in the answer up there.